# Xlookup returns different values when used on same workbook vs. external workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, xlookup

I'm trying to compare data recently pulled from a database into an excel spreadsheet to one pulled about 2 months ago. When I use Xlookup to find my array in the current workbook I get one array based on the Key I'm looking for. However, when I use Xlookup to find the same key in the older spreadsheet data, I get a completely different key's data.

I've trying going from spreadsheet a-b and b-a. Same result. I've truncated the array to a single cell's data. I've written VBA code for the worksheet function. Same results for all.

```
=XLOOKUP(EO3,BK:BK,AL:BJ,"",0,1)
=XLOOKUP($EO3,'[01-29-2024.xlsm]Step'!$BK:$BK,$AL:$BJ,"",0,1)
Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup([EO3], [BK:BK], [AL:BJ], "", 0, 1)
Test = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup([EO3], Workbooks("01-29-2024.xlsm").Sheets("Step").Range("BL:$BL"), [$AL:$BJ], "", 0, 1)
```

[image]

[image]

Initially I thought I saw that excel was truncating my Key from:`123400000000-000000-002` to: `1234000000000-000000-2`.

I spent some time trying to format the key differently, but I have not been able to correct the issue. I verified Key is text using

```
=ISTEXT(EO3)
```

result is TRUE.

Sorry for the redacted image/key. Customer data.

Comment: I would use a specific (worksheet-qualified) range for all inputs, and avoid the "Activesheet" `[EO3]` notation.  The context you get from running the lookup in a worksheet cell is not there when you run it via VBA.

Comment: Probably should be: `=XLOOKUP($EO3,'[01-29-2024.xlsm]Step'!$BK:$BK,'[01-29-2024.xlsm]Step'!$AL:$BJ,"",0,1)`

Comment: OK. Got it. Second sheet call out missing was causing it to pull the row of data from the original file, not the lookup file. Thanks!